# Pasar y recibir información de una vista a otra en CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Cómo le podría hacer para lo siguiente:

```
<? foreach($artist as $row): 
<a href="<?= base_url() ?>artista/artistax/<?= $row->idArtist ?>">
<img src="<?= base_url() ?>admin/img/<?= $row->imagen ?>">
</a>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, pero cuando ingresa a esa liga, me aparece que no esta definida la variable.

Lo que necesito es que me genere todos los demás campos de la tabla, para poder plasmarlos. ¿Cómo sería eso?

Comment: Que es lo que quieres pasar a la otra vista?

Comment: mira quiero url amigables, ahorita como tengo mi liga es así:
/artistx?id=10

Entonces en esa vista hago una consulta que cuando mi id sea = 10 me recolecte toda la informacion de ese id

Entonces quiero que mi url quede artistx/10/  
y al entrar me recolecte la información

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es pasar esos parámetros por `POST`, actualmente lo estas haciendo por medio de `GET`, puedes pasar esa información por medio de un formulario indicando en el `ACTION` la url de tu función en el controlador. El formulario no necesariamente tiene que ser visible, practicamente puedes indicarle por medio de `Javascript` que cuando presionen algún botón envie el formulario hacia el `ACTION` que le estas indicando.

Vista:

```
<form id="form" role="form" action="<?echo base_url('Index/ads')?>" method="POST" hidden="true">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="id" name="form[id]" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 left">
            <button class="send" type="submit"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery.min.js');?>"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.action').click(function(){
            var st = $(this).attr('name');
            $('#id').attr('value',st);
            $('.send').click();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controlador:

```
public function ads()
    {
        if (isset($_POST['form'])) {
            $data['id'] = $_POST['form']['id'];
            $data['Title'] = "Titulo";
            /**
             * Cargar vista con datos
             */
            $this->load->view('ads',$data);
        }else{
            redirect('index', 'refresh');
        }
}
```

En la vista donde quieres mostrar esos datos únicamente lo muestras con $id (en mi caso) y si miras estoy cargando la vista ads, en tu caso ya sera el nombre que le asignes y si quieres ver que si te este pasando los datos has un `var_dump()` de tu variable para que veas el contenido.